# Error while trying to build schema in symfony1.4 project

Tags: configuration, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to build up a new project with Symfony1.4.
I'm not new to Symfony but today I faced with a new problem, never seen before.
When trying to run

```
php symfony doctrine:build-schema
```

i revieve this error

```
Warning: mkdir(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 10045   
is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in /var/www/vhosts/my site.it/httpdocs/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/
doctrine/Doctrine/Lib.php on line 292
```

So, my question is, how can I solve this problem?
It seems that doctrine save a temporary file in /tmp dir, where I cannot access.
Can I maybe change it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The error seems to be occurring because Symfony is trying to create a directory and it's incapable of doing so because of permissions.

If you open

`/var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Lib.php`

You can see this line of code on 292

```
return mkdir(trim($path), $mode, true);
```

`$path` contains the path to a directory that Doctrine is trying to unsuccessfully generate. It could be your `mysite.it\httpdocs\data` directory where the fixtures or `schema.yml` is kept.

Try doing a `die(var_dump($path));` just before the above line to see what the path of the directory is. Then you might need to physically create it yourself on the file system.